# how to call external API with Authorization header from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have been trying to call external API using SharePoint hosted Addin past few day ,Due to CORS policy I have been using SP.RequestExecutor for last few days and i'm still unable to call the API, and I get unauthorized error when I run the code.I would appreciate any help regarding this matter.

```
 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(API_address);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: API_address,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
            headers: { "Authorization": value},
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched for using provider hosted app for calling external API and it works. And I used Http client for calling the API.

```
    static async Task<string> GetRequest(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //setup client
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            //make request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestPath);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

unauthorized means Error-401. 401 returns the way you need to authenticate. Please check there what kind of authentication you need. 
In C# i used credentials to realize my needed NTLM Authentication:

```
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(uri, "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, server));
endpointRequest.Credentials = cache;
```